# ImportError: cannot import name suppress

Tags: python, import

I am trying to install [Taiga](http://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/setup-production.html) on my computer, and for one of the scripts its trying to `import suppress` but failing. I tried doing this manually:

```
(taiga)$ python
Python 3.3.3 (default, Nov 27 2013, 17:12:35) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from contextlib import suppress
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name suppress
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) requires Python 3.4 or later. So, either Taiga requires Python 3.4 or later (which should be documented), or it's got a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation for Taiga](http://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/), among the requirements is:

> Python 3.4

So, you should not expect it to work in Python 3.3.

And that's exactly your problem here. The [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) function is "New in version 3.4."

Comment: Ah ok, I was hoping that wouldn't be the case. I will now need to hack LMDE to force a `python` upgrade. Thanks!

Comment: @codehitman: I thought the whole point of LMDE was to include Debian packages that haven't made it into normal Mint yet? Does it really not have a Python 3.4 package?

Comment: Nope :( Getting tired of hacking linux just to get something running at this point. If I wasn't on a student budget I'd buy a Mac.

Comment: Nope, building from source- faster!

Comment: @codehitman: Even with no budget, why not use a more popular distro like Ubuntu or Fedora instead of a minor/specialist fork of a smaller distro?

Comment: I had gotten sick of Unity, when it had first come out. So I decided to switch. In my naivety of undergrad enthusiasm, I decided to choose LMDE. It was new then. I have been using it for several years now. Recently, installed Fedora on my personal server, just to play with RPM and Fedora in general. But still consider it a pretty big task to completely erase and reinstall linux on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a situation that has to use Python 2. You can try to install the module `contextlib2` version between 0.5 and 0.6, such as `pip install contextlib2==0.5.5`.

I meet the problem several times, and it still works for me.